# SVG graph not working

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, svg

I am trying to make an interactive svg chart. Here is a javascript for it.

```
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
            // Main is for charts and mini is for slider which would be below the chart
            var main_margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 100, left: 40},
                mini_margin = {top: 430, right: 80, bottom: 20, left: 40},
                main_width = 960 - main_margin.left - main_margin.right,
                main_height = 500 - main_margin.top - main_margin.bottom,
                mini_height = 500 - mini_margin.top - mini_margin.bottom;

            // Parse the date / time
            var formatDate = d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y"), 
                parseDate = formatDate.parse,
                bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.Date; }).left, 
                formatOutput0 = function(d) { return formatDate(d.Date) + " - " + d.Nifty; }, 
                formatOutput1 = function(d) { return formatDate(d.Date) + " - " + d.Sensex; };

            // Set the ranges for x 
            var main_x = d3.time.scale()
                .range([0, main_width]),
                mini_x = d3.time.scale()
                .range([0, main_width]);

            // Set the ranges for y
            var main_y0 = d3.scale.sqrt()
                .range([main_height, 0]),
                main_y1 = d3.scale.sqrt()
                .range([main_height, 0]),
                mini_y0 = d3.scale.sqrt()
                .range([mini_height, 0]),
                mini_y1 = d3.scale.sqrt()
                .range([mini_height, 0]);

            // Define the axes
            var main_xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(main_x)
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y"))
                .orient("bottom"),
                mini_xAxis = d3.svg.axis() //this is for slider
                .scale(mini_x)
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d-%m-%Y"))
                .orient("bottom");

            var main_yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(main_y0)
                .orient("left");
                main_yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(main_y1)
                .orient("right");

            //Creating a slider
            var brush = d3.svg.brush()
                .x(mini_x)
                .on("brush", brush);

            // Define the line
            var main_line0 = d3.svg.line()
                .interpolate("cardinal")
                .x(function(d) { return main_x(d.Date); })
                .y(function(d) { return main_y0(d.Nifty); });

            var main_line1 = d3.svg.line()
                .interpolate("cardinal")
                .x(function(d) { return main_x(d.Date); })
                .y(function(d) { return main_y1(d.Sensex); });

            var mini_line0 = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return mini_x(d.Date); })
                .y(function(d) { return mini_y0(d.Nifty); });

            var mini_line1 = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return mini_x(d.Date); })
                .y(function(d) { return mini_y1(d.Sensex); });

            // Adds the svg canvas
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                              .append("svg")
                              .attr("width", main_width + main_margin.left + main_margin.right)
                              .attr("height", main_height + main_margin.top + main_margin.bottom)

                              svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
                              .attr("id", "clip")
                              .append("rect")
                              .attr("width", main_width)
                              .attr("height", main_height);

            var main = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + main_margin.left + "," + main_margin.top + ")");

            var mini = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + mini_margin.left + "," + mini_margin.top + ")");


            // Get the data

            var data={
                "Date":["2014-11-07","2014-11-10","2014-11-11","2014-11-12","2014-11-13","2014-11-14","2014-11-17","2014-11-18","2014-11-19","2014-11-20","2014-11-21","2014-11-24","2014-11-25","2014-11-26","2014-11-27","2014-11-28","2014-12-01","2014-12-02","2014-12-03","2014-12-04","2014-12-05","2014-12-08","2014-12-09","2014-12-10","2014-12-11","2014-12-12","2014-12-15","2014-12-16","2014-12-17","2014-12-18","2014-12-19","2014-12-22","2014-12-23","2014-12-24","2014-12-26","2014-12-29","2014-12-30","2014-12-31","2015-01-01","2015-01-02","2015-01-05","2015-01-06","2015-01-07","2015-01-08","2015-01-09","2015-01-12","2015-01-13","2015-01-14","2015-01-15","2015-01-16","2015-01-19","2015-01-20","2015-01-21","2015-01-22","2015-01-23","2015-01-27","2015-01-28","2015-01-29","2015-01-30","2015-02-02","2015-02-03","2015-02-04","2015-02-05","2015-02-06","2015-02-09","2015-02-10","2015-02-11","2015-02-12","2015-02-13","2015-02-16","2015-02-18","2015-02-19","2015-02-20","2015-02-23","2015-02-24","2015-02-25","2015-02-26","2015-02-27","2015-02-28","2015-03-02","2015-03-03","2015-03-04","2015-03-05","2015-03-09","2015-03-10","2015-03-11","2015-03-12","2015-03-13","2015-03-16","2015-03-17","2015-03-18","2015-03-19","2015-03-20","2015-03-23","2015-03-24","2015-03-25","2015-03-26","2015-03-27","2015-03-30","2015-03-31","2015-04-01","2015-04-06","2015-04-07","2015-04-08","2015-04-09","2015-04-10","2015-04-13","2015-04-15","2015-04-16","2015-04-17","2015-04-20","2015-04-21","2015-04-22","2015-04-23","2015-04-24","2015-04-27","2015-04-28","2015-04-29","2015-04-30","2015-05-04","2015-05-05","2015-05-06","2015-05-07","2015-05-08","2015-05-11","2015-05-12","2015-05-13","2015-05-14","2015-05-15","2015-05-18","2015-05-19","2015-05-20","2015-05-21","2015-05-22","2015-05-25","2015-05-26","2015-05-27","2015-05-28","2015-05-29","2015-06-01","2015-06-02","2015-06-03","2015-06-04","2015-06-05","2015-06-08","2015-06-09","2015-06-10","2015-06-11","2015-06-12","2015-06-15","2015-06-16","2015-06-17","2015-06-18","2015-06-19","2015-06-22","2015-06-23","2015-06-24","2015-06-25","2015-06-26","2015-06-29","2015-06-30","2015-07-01","2015-07-02","2015-07-03","2015-07-06","2015-07-07","2015-07-08","2015-07-09","2015-07-10","2015-07-13","2015-07-14","2015-07-15","2015-07-16","2015-07-17","2015-07-20","2015-07-21","2015-07-22","2015-07-23","2015-07-24","2015-07-27","2015-07-28","2015-07-29","2015-07-30","2015-07-31","2015-08-03","2015-08-04","2015-08-05","2015-08-06","2015-08-07","2015-08-10","2015-08-11","2015-08-12","2015-08-13","2015-08-14","2015-08-17","2015-08-18","2015-08-19","2015-08-20","2015-08-21","2015-08-24","2015-08-25","2015-08-26","2015-08-27","2015-08-28","2015-08-31","2015-09-01","2015-09-02","2015-09-03","2015-09-04","2015-09-07","2015-09-08","2015-09-09","2015-09-10","2015-09-11","2015-09-14","2015-09-15","2015-09-16","2015-09-18","2015-09-21","2015-09-22","2015-09-23","2015-09-24","2015-09-28","2015-09-29","2015-09-30","2015-10-01","2015-10-05","2015-10-06","2015-10-07","2015-10-08","2015-10-09","2015-10-12","2015-10-13","2015-10-14","2015-10-15","2015-10-16","2015-10-19","2015-10-20","2015-10-21","2015-10-23","2015-10-26","2015-10-27","2015-10-28","2015-10-29","2015-10-30","2015-11-02","2015-11-03","2015-11-04","2015-11-05"],"Nifty":[8337,8344.25,8362.65,8383.3,8357.85,8389.9,8430.75,8425.9,8382.3,8401.9,8477.35,8530.15,8463.1,8475.75,8494.2,8588.25,8555.9,8524.7,8537.65,8564.4,8538.3,8438.25,8340.7,8355.65,8292.9,8224.1,8219.6,8067.6,8029.8,8159.3,8225.2,8324,8267,8174.1,8200.7,8246.3,8248.25,8282.7,8284,8395.45,8378.4,8127.35,8102.1,8234.6,8284.5,8323,8299.4,8277.55,8494.15,8513.8,8550.7,8695.6,8729.5,8761.4,8835.6,8910.5,8914.3,8952.35,8808.9,8797.4,8756.55,8723.7,8711.7,8661.05,8526.35,8565.55,8627.4,8711.55,8805.5,8809.35,8869.1,8895.3,8833.6,8754.95,8762.1,8767.25,8683.85,8844.6,8901.85,8956.75,8996.25,8922.65,8937.75,8756.75,8712.05,8699.95,8776,8647.75,8633.15,8723.3,8685.9,8634.65,8570.9,8550.9,8542.95,8530.8,8342.15,8341.4,8492.3,8491,8586.25,8659.9,8660.3,8714.4,8778.3,8780.35,8834,8750.2,8706.7,8606,8448.1,8377.75,8429.7,8398.3,8305.25,8213.8,8285.6,8239.75,8181.5,8331.95,8324.8,8097,8057.3,8191.5,8325.25,8126.95,8235.45,8224.2,8262.35,8373.65,8365.65,8423.25,8421,8458.95,8370.25,8339.35,8334.6,8319,8433.65,8433.4,8236.45,8135.1,8130.65,8114.7,8044.15,8022.4,8124.45,7965.35,7982.9,8013.9,8047.3,8091.55,8174.6,8224.95,8353.1,8381.55,8360.85,8398,8381.1,8318.4,8368.5,8453.05,8444.9,8484.9,8522.15,8510.8,8363.05,8328.55,8360.55,8459.65,8454.1,8523.8,8608.05,8609.85,8603.45,8529.45,8633.5,8589.8,8521.55,8361,8337,8375.05,8421.8,8532.85,8543.05,8516.9,8567.95,8588.65,8564.6,8525.6,8462.35,8349.45,8355.85,8518.55,8477.3,8466.55,8495.15,8372.75,8299.95,7809,7880.7,7791.85,7948.95,8001.95,7971.3,7785.85,7717,7823,7655.05,7558.8,7688.25,7818.6,7788.1,7789.3,7872.25,7829.1,7899.15,7981.9,7977.1,7812,7845.95,7868.5,7795.7,7843.3,7948.9,7950.9,8119.3,8152.9,8177.4,8129.35,8189.7,8143.6,8131.7,8107.9,8179.5,8238.15,8275.05,8261.65,8251.7,8295.45,8260.55,8232.9,8171.2,8111.75,8065.8,8050.8,8060.7,8040.2,7955.45],"Sensex":[27868.63,27874.73,27910.06,28008.9,27940.64,28046.66,28177.88,28163.29,28032.85,28067.56,28334.63,28499.54,28338.05,28386.19,28438.91,28693.99,28559.62,28444.01,28442.71,28562.82,28458.1,28119.4,27797.01,27831.1,27602.01,27350.68,27319.56,26781.44,26710.13,27126.57,27371.84,27701.79,27506.46,27208.61,27241.78,27395.73,27403.54,27499.42,27507.54,27887.9,27842.32,26987.46,26908.82,27274.71,27458.38,27585.27,27425.73,27346.82,28075.55,28121.89,28262.01,28784.67,28888.86,29006.02,29278.84,29571.04,29559.18,29681.77,29182.95,29122.27,29000.14,28883.11,28850.97,28717.91,28227.39,28355.62,28533.97,28805.1,29094.93,29135.88,29320.26,29462.27,29231.41,28975.11,29004.66,29007.99,28746.65,29220.12,29361.5,29459.14,29593.73,29380.73,29448.95,28844.78,28709.87,28659.17,28930.41,28503.3,28437.71,28736.38,28622.12,28469.67,28261.08,28192.02,28161.72,28111.83,27457.58,27458.64,27975.86,27957.49,28260.14,28504.46,28516.59,28707.75,28885.21,28879.38,29044.44,28799.69,28666.04,28442.1,27886.21,27676.04,27890.13,27735.02,27437.94,27176.99,27396.38,27225.93,27011.31,27490.59,27440.14,26717.37,26599.11,27105.39,27507.3,26877.48,27251.1,27206.06,27324,27687.3,27645.53,27837.21,27809.35,27957.5,27643.88,27531.41,27564.66,27506.71,27828.44,27848.99,27188.38,26837.2,26813.42,26768.49,26523.09,26481.25,26840.5,26370.98,26425.3,26586.55,26686.51,26832.66,27115.83,27316.17,27730.21,27804.37,27729.67,27895.97,27811.84,27645.15,27780.83,28020.87,27945.8,28092.79,28208.76,28171.69,27687.72,27573.66,27661.4,27961.19,27932.9,28198.29,28446.12,28463.31,28420.12,28182.14,28504.93,28370.84,28112.31,27561.38,27459.23,27563.43,27705.35,28114.56,28187.06,28071.93,28223.08,28298.13,28236.39,28101.72,27866.09,27512.26,27549.53,28067.31,27878.27,27831.54,27931.64,27607.82,27366.07,25741.56,26032.38,25714.66,26231.19,26392.38,26283.09,25696.44,25453.56,25764.78,25201.9,24893.81,25317.87,25719.58,25622.17,25610.21,25856.7,25705.93,25963.97,26218.91,26192.98,25651.84,25822.99,25863.5,25616.84,25778.66,26154.83,26220.95,26785.55,26932.88,27035.85,26845.81,27079.51,26904.11,26846.53,26779.66,27010.14,27214.6,27364.92,27306.83,27287.66,27470.81,27361.96,27253.44,27039.76,26838.14,26656.83,26559.15,26590.59,26552.92,26304.2]
            }


            d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
              data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.Date = parseDate(d.Date);
                d.Nifty = +d.Nifty;
                d.Sensex = +d.Sensex;
              });

              data.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.Date - b.Date;
              });

            // Scale the range of the data
              main_x.domain([data[0].Date, data[data.length - 1].Date]);
              main_y0.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Nifty; }));
              main_y0.domain([0.1, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Nifty; })]);
              main_y1.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Sensex; }));
              mini_x.domain(main_x.domain());
              mini_y0.domain(main_y0.domain());
              mini_y1.domain(main_y1.domain());

            // Add the valueline path.
              main.append("path")
                  .datum(data)
                  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
                  .attr("class", "line line0")
                  .attr("d", main_line0);

              main.append("path")
                  .datum(data)
                  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
                  .attr("class", "line line1")
                  .attr("d", main_line1);

            // Add the X Axis
              main.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "x axis")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + main_height + ")")
                  .call(main_xAxis);

            // Add the Y1 Axis
              main.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis axisLeft")
                  .call(main_yAxisLeft)
                .append("text")
                  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                  .attr("y", 6)
                  .attr("dy", ".71em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                  .text("Nifty");

            // Add the Y2 Axis
              main.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis axisRight")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + main_width + ", 0)")
                  .call(main_yAxisRight)
                .append("text")
                  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                  .attr("y", -12)
                  .attr("dy", ".71em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                  .text("Sensex");


            // Add the valueline path for slider
              mini.append("path")
                  .datum(data)
                  .attr("class", "line")
                  .attr("d", mini_line0);

              mini.append("path")
                  .datum(data)
                  .attr("class", "line")
                  .attr("d", mini_line1);

              mini.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "x brush")
                  .call(brush)
                .selectAll("rect")
                  .attr("y", -6)
                  .attr("height", mini_height + 7);

              var focus = main.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "focus")
                  .style("display", "none");

              // Display on the timeline
              focus.append("line")
                  .attr("class", "x")
                  .attr("y1", main_y0(0) - 6)
                  .attr("y2", main_y0(0) + 6)

              // Display on the left bar
              focus.append("line")
                  .attr("class", "y0")
                  .attr("x1", main_width - 6) // nach links
                  .attr("x2", main_width + 6); // nach rechts

              // Ad on the right bar
              focus.append("line")
                  .attr("class", "y1")
                  .attr("x1", main_width - 6)
                  .attr("x2", main_width + 6);

            // append the circle at the intersection
              focus.append("circle")
                  .attr("class", "y0")
                  .attr("r", 4);

            // append the text at the intersection of x axis and y0
              focus.append("text")
                  .attr("class", "y0")
                  .attr("dy", "-1em");

            // append the circle at the intersection
              focus.append("circle")
                  .attr("class", "y1")
                  .attr("r", 4);
            // append the text at the intersection of x axis and y1
              focus.append("text")
                  .attr("class", "y1")
                  .attr("dy", "-1em");

            // The rectangle for slider
              main.append("rect")
                  .attr("class", "overlay")
                  .attr("width", main_width)
                  .attr("height", main_height)
                  .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
                  .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
                  .on("mousemove", mousemove);

            //Mouse move function for creating a slider
             function mousemove() {
                var x0 = main_x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
                    i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
                    d0 = data[i - 1],
                    d1 = data[i],
                    d = x0 - d0.Date > d1.Date - x0 ? d1 : d0;
                focus.select("circle.y0").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_x(d.Date) + "," + main_y0(d.Nifty) + ")");
                focus.select("text.y0").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_x(d.Date) + "," + main_y0(d.Nifty) + ")").text(formatOutput0(d));
                focus.select("circle.y1").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_x(d.Date) + "," + main_y1(d.Sensex) + ")");
                focus.select("text.y1").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_x(d.Date) + "," + main_y1(d.Sensex) + ")").text(formatOutput1(d));
                focus.select(".x").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_x(d.Date) + ",0)");
                focus.select(".y0").attr("transform", "translate(" + main_width * -1 + ", " + main_y0(d.Nifty) + ")").attr("x2", main_width + main_x(d.Date));
                focus.select(".y1").attr("transform", "translate(0, " + main_y1(d.Sensex) + ")").attr("x1", main_x(d.Date));
              }
            });

            function brush() {
              main_x.domain(brush.empty() ? mini_x.domain() : brush.extent());
              main.select(".line0").attr("d", main_line0);
              main.select(".line1").attr("d", main_line1);
              main.select(".x.axis").call(main_xAxis);
            }
```

Data is in csv format. here is a excerpt from the csv file.

```
                Date     Nifty  Sensex
            07-11-2014  8337    27868.63
            10-11-2014  8344.25 27874.73
            11-11-2014  8362.65 27910.06
            12-11-2014  8383.3  28008.9
            13-11-2014  8357.85 27940.64
            14-11-2014  8389.9  28046.66
            17-11-2014  8430.75 28177.88
            18-11-2014  8425.9  28163.29
            19-11-2014  8382.3  28032.85
            20-11-2014  8401.9  28067.56
            21-11-2014  8477.35 28334.63
            24-11-2014  8530.15 28499.54
            25-11-2014  8463.1  28338.05
            26-11-2014  8475.75 28386.19
            27-11-2014  8494.2  28438.91
```

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
              <title>MArket Performance</title>

              <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            </head>
            <style type="text/css"></style> 


            <body>
            <h2>Hello!!</h2>


            <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
                <div id="chart">
                  <svg id="dateChart"></svg>
                </div>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

No chart is being made. I have checked for a syntax error but there is none. 
Kindly if some one can review it .

Comment: Are there any errors on the console? Could you provide a live demo?

Comment: Check "Elements" panel to see the DOM structure of your visualization.

Comment: [Your code works for me](http://plnkr.co/edit/gByZwcp5pI21VwykSUAi?p=preview)

Comment: @sergeyz I have tried that but over there too it is showing no chart.

Comment: @Mark I am surprised how is it happening. Can you help me to get it in this format. (http://bl.ocks.org/gniemetz/4618602 )

Comment: @altocumulus (http://plnkr.co/edit/QRprSr1GFYaFgW2cTczT?p=preview) here is a live demo

Comment: I was just about to scold you for not listening to my advice to look at the console until I realized, that it's only Chrome which will log the error :-/ In your Plunk's `<script>` you are referencing  a local `src="D:/..."`. You need to adjust the path to reference the `Javascript.js` belonging to the Plunk and throw in some more styling sugar. And, lo and behold, you got a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/oOVCOqh1gB8c4zKp1Pwa?p=preview) much like the one put together by @Mark.

Comment: @altocumulus thanks for the reply. I am new to web development. Because of it i am committing these silly mistakes. Can you tell me why is my graph not working like (http://bl.ocks.org/gniemetz/4618602) this but i am using the code provided there only. Even after removing the styling it doesn't work as per required.

Comment: Have a look at the [updated plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/oOVCOqh1gB8c4zKp1Pwa?p=preview). I have adjusted the styling and added the x axis to the second chart area. This way it looks and feel like the example you linked to. Apart from the look-and-feel there is a logical error in your code where you are accidentally overwriting the domain of your `main_y0` scale by calling `main_y0.domain()` twice (line 107). Removing this should put you back on track.

Comment: @altocumulus Thank you so much for your help. It works great!! Can't i run this directly on local host?

Comment: @altocumulus I figured it out!! Thanks